# Drawing fancy rectangle around face

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, dlib

I am using the following code to detect face and draw rectangle on top of the face.

```
while True:
    # get video frame
    ret, img = cap.read()

    input_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    img_h, img_w, _ = np.shape(input_img)

    detected = detector(input_img, 1)

    for i, d in enumerate(detected):
        x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h = d.left(), d.top(), d.right() + 1, d.bottom() + 1, d.width(), d.height()
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("result", img)
    key = cv2.waitKey(30)

    if key == 27:
        break
```

The rectangle appears to be like this:

[image]

However Im trying to get a rectangle similar to this:

[image]

Is there any OpenCV or dlib function that can help me get this sort of effective rectangle?

Comment: There are various drawing functions that let you draw [lines](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) and [arcs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse). Seems like everything you need to achieve what you want.

Comment: Oops, Page not found.

Comment: @DheerajMPai Good catch. I managed to find the images (fortunately the path only slightly changed) and I uploaded them locally so it should be good in the future. Thanks (and thanks for the bounty :) )

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can achieve what you want by using the functions that draw [lines](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#line) and [arcs](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/drawing_functions.html#ellipse).

The frame you want to draw consists of 4 similar parts (one per corner), each rotated (or mirrored).

Let's have a look at the top left corner:

[image: Illustration]

As you can see, we need to draw 2 line segments (of length `d`) and an arc (a quarter of a circle of radius `r`).

Let's say the coordinates of the top-left corner are `(x1, y1)`.

That means that the arc will have a center at position `(x1 + r, y1 + r)`.

One of the lines will go from `(x1 + r, y1)` to `(x1 + r + d, y1)`.

The other line will go from `(x1, y1 + r)` to `(x1, y1 + r + d)`.

Similar situation will happen with the other corners.

---

**Sample code:**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# ============================================================================

def draw_border(img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness, r, d):
    x1,y1 = pt1
    x2,y2 = pt2

    # Top left
    cv2.line(img, (x1 + r, y1), (x1 + r + d, y1), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1 + r), (x1, y1 + r + d), color, thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (x1 + r, y1 + r), (r, r), 180, 0, 90, color, thickness)

    # Top right
    cv2.line(img, (x2 - r, y1), (x2 - r - d, y1), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (x2, y1 + r), (x2, y1 + r + d), color, thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (x2 - r, y1 + r), (r, r), 270, 0, 90, color, thickness)

    # Bottom left
    cv2.line(img, (x1 + r, y2), (x1 + r + d, y2), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y2 - r), (x1, y2 - r - d), color, thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (x1 + r, y2 - r), (r, r), 90, 0, 90, color, thickness)

    # Bottom right
    cv2.line(img, (x2 - r, y2), (x2 - r - d, y2), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (x2, y2 - r), (x2, y2 - r - d), color, thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (x2 - r, y2 - r), (r, r), 0, 0, 90, color, thickness)

# ============================================================================

img = np.zeros((256,256,3), dtype=np.uint8)

draw_border(img, (10,10), (100, 100), (127,255,255), 1, 10, 20)
draw_border(img, (128,128), (240, 160), (255,255,127), 1, 5, 5)

cv2.imwrite('round_rect.png', img)
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: you are a super genius!

Comment: Fantastic!! This was really really helpful! I was too board to look at the dumb green rectangular output

Comment: If I had more reps. I would have given all of them as bounty

Answer (score 3):

I did something naive. You can implement with further modifications using a function.

### ***Steps:***

1. I manually marked a rectangle around the text and extracted the 4 points.
2. Then I fixed a length for the line to be drawn from these 4 points.

**Result:**

[image]

Functions used:

- `cv2.line()`
- `cv2.rectangle()`

See [THIS LINK](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dc/da5/tutorial_py_drawing_functions.html) for details about their usage.

Comment: The answer above your's is superb. May be you can edit

Comment: No may be you add the entire code. Instead of just adding the link

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for a function/lib that lets you make fancy rectangles, the following tactic might be easier:

**Step 1** - Download an image of the rectangle that you want, such that it should only contain the 4 strokes at the corner, **and the rest of the background should be black**.

**Step 2** - In your code, use `imread` to save this image as a Mat object:

`border = cv2.imread('your_img.jpg')`

**Step 3** - Modify your `for` loop to **superimpose the `border` Mat on the detected rectangle**, as shown below:

```
for i, d in enumerate(detected):
    x1, y1, x2, y2, w, h = d.left(), d.top(), d.right() + 1, d.bottom() + 1, d.width(), d.height()

    #cv2.rectangle won't be needed anymore
    #cv2.rectangle(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)

    roi=img[y1+h/2-100:y1+h/2+100,x1+w/2-100:x1+w/2+100]
    #this points to a section in original image
    cv2.addWeighted(roi,1,border,1,0,roi)
```

Ensure that the size of `roi` and `border` is the same, or your code will crash.

This will superimpose the corner strokes on your input frame, and neglect the black background.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Drawing Fancy Rectangle]

Thanks to @Dan Mašek for his suggestions. You can easily draw a fancy rectangle by like this way. You can check the full details Here: [Drawing Fancy Round Rectangle around the Face](https://www.life2coding.com/drawing-fancy-round-rectangle-around-face-using-opencv-python/)

```
def draw_border(img, pt1, pt2, color, thickness, r, d):
    x1,y1 = pt1
    x2,y2 = pt2

    # Top left
    cv2.line(img, (x1 + r, y1), (x1 + r + d, y1), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1 + r), (x1, y1 + r + d), color, thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (x1 + r, y1 + r), (r, r), 180, 0, 90, color, thickness)

    # Top right
    cv2.line(img, (x2 - r, y1), (x2 - r - d, y1), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (x2, y1 + r), (x2, y1 + r + d), color, thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (x2 - r, y1 + r), (r, r), 270, 0, 90, color, thickness)

    # Bottom left
    cv2.line(img, (x1 + r, y2), (x1 + r + d, y2), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y2 - r), (x1, y2 - r - d), color, thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (x1 + r, y2 - r), (r, r), 90, 0, 90, color, thickness)

    # Bottom right
    cv2.line(img, (x2 - r, y2), (x2 - r - d, y2), color, thickness)
    cv2.line(img, (x2, y2 - r), (x2, y2 - r - d), color, thickness)
    cv2.ellipse(img, (x2 - r, y2 - r), (r, r), 0, 0, 90, color, thickness)


def detect(path,img):
    cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(path)

    img=cv2.imread(img,1)
    # converting to gray image for faster video processing
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    rects = cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.2, 3,minSize=(50, 50))
    # if at least 1 face detected
    if len(rects) >= 0:
        # Draw a rectangle around the faces
        for (x, y, w, h) in rects:
            draw_border(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 105),4, 15, 10)
        # Display the resulting frame
        cv2.imshow('Face Detection', img)
        # wait for 'c' to close the application
        cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: you have just copy pasted the first answer dude, anyways thanks

Comment: That's why I have also given him thanks for his code. I think you didn't read my comment on that properly. Check it properly and I tried to answer the question with Face detection and fancy rectangle.