# Python-Opencv:how to draw not complete rectangle with four corners on image

Tags: python, opencv, draw

After searching in the net, I could not find a way to draw a bounding box like the one in [this](http://www.3divi.com/images/solutions/Papilon_APFIS.jpg) image using OpenCV in Python. It has two features first four corners which are not connected with each other and second one the transparent bounding box.

I know I should use Polygon, but I can not go further that this point.

Comment: Could you identify 4 corners?

Comment: How about drawing 8 lines and a rectangle

Comment: please check out the accepted response. It is what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following function draws an incomplete rectangle around the region of interest. I made use of `cv2.line()` twice for each point provided. Additionally I also made use of `cv2.circle()` to mark the 4 points.

There is one constraint. You will have to provide the 4 points in the following order: **top-left, bottom-left, top-right, bottom-right**.

Also there is an option to vary the length of the line you want to draw `line_length`.

**Code:**

```
def draw_border(img, point1, point2, point3, point4, line_length):

    x1, y1 = point1
    x2, y2 = point2
    x3, y3 = point3
    x4, y4 = point4    

    cv2.circle(img, (x1, y1), 3, (255, 0, 255), -1)    #-- top_left
    cv2.circle(img, (x2, y2), 3, (255, 0, 255), -1)    #-- bottom-left
    cv2.circle(img, (x3, y3), 3, (255, 0, 255), -1)    #-- top-right
    cv2.circle(img, (x4, y4), 3, (255, 0, 255), -1)    #-- bottom-right

    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x1 , y1 + line_length), (0, 255, 0), 2)  #-- top-left
    cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x1 + line_length , y1), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.line(img, (x2, y2), (x2 , y2 - line_length), (0, 255, 0), 2)  #-- bottom-left
    cv2.line(img, (x2, y2), (x2 + line_length , y2), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.line(img, (x3, y3), (x3 - line_length, y3), (0, 255, 0), 2)  #-- top-right
    cv2.line(img, (x3, y3), (x3, y3 + line_length), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    cv2.line(img, (x4, y4), (x4 , y4 - line_length), (0, 255, 0), 2)  #-- bottom-right
    cv2.line(img, (x4, y4), (x4 - line_length , y4), (0, 255, 0), 2)

    return img

line_length = 15

img = np.zeros((512,512,3), np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('img', img)

point1, point2, point3, point4 = (280,330), (280,390), (340,330), (340,390)
fin_img = draw_border(img, point1, point2, point3, point4, line_length)

cv2.imshow('fin_img', fin_img)

cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: @MajidAzimi Cjeck out [THIS ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46036477/drawing-fancy-rectangle-around-face) for drawing rectangle with curved edges

Answer (score -1):

Try this code. Might be helpful for you.

**Code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = np.array(Image.open('Image.jpg'), dtype=np.uint8)

# Create figure and axes
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1)

# Display the image
ax.imshow(image)

# Create a Rectangle patch
rect = patches.Rectangle((102,55),160,162,linewidth=1,edgecolor='r',facecolor='none')

# Add the patch to the Axes
ax.add_patch(rect)

plt.show()
```

**Image Output:**

[image: Output Would be like this]

Comment: thanks Muhammad, but this is not what I needed. Please check out the accepted response.

Answer (score -1):

Also if someone needs: Fancy rectangle with curved corners in C:
However I needed this code in python was replied by the community.

```
void draw_border(IplImage* show_img, CvPoint pt1, CvPoint pt2, CvScalar color, int thickness, int r, int d):

        // Top left
        cvLine(show_img, cvPoint( pt1.x +r, pt1.y), cvPoint( pt1.x + r + d, pt1.y), color, thickness, 8, 0 );
        cvLine(show_img, cvPoint( pt1.x, pt1.y + r), cvPoint( pt1.x, pt1.y + r + d), color, thickness, 8, 0 );
        cvEllipse(show_img, cvPoint(pt1.x +r, pt1.y + r), cvSize( r, r ), 180, 0, 90, color, thickness, 8, 0);

        // Top right
            cvLine(show_img, cvPoint( pt2.x - r, pt1.y), cvPoint( pt2.x - r - d, pt1.y), color, thickness,  8, 0 );
            cvLine(show_img, cvPoint( pt2.x, pt1.y + r), cvPoint( pt2.x, pt1.y + r + d), color, thickness,  8, 0 );
        cvEllipse(show_img, cvPoint(pt2.x -r, pt1.y + r), cvSize( r, r ), 270, 0, 90, color, thickness, 8, 0);


            // Bottom left
            cvLine(show_img, cvPoint( pt1.x + r, pt2.y), cvPoint( pt1.x + r + d, pt2.y), color, thickness,  8, 0);
            cvLine(show_img, cvPoint( pt1.x, pt2.y - r), cvPoint( pt1.x, pt2.y - r - d), color, thickness,  8, 0);
        cvEllipse(show_img, cvPoint(pt1.x  + r, pt2.y - r), cvSize( r, r ), 90, 0, 90, color, thickness, 8, 0);

            // Bottom right
            cvLine(show_img, cvPoint( pt2.x - r, pt2.y), cvPoint( pt2.x - r - d, pt2.y), color, thickness, 8, 0);
            cvLine(show_img, cvPoint( pt2.x, pt2.y - r), cvPoint( pt2.x, pt2.y - r - d), color, thickness, 8, 0);
        cvEllipse(show_img, cvPoint(pt2.x  - r, pt2.y - r), cvSize( r, r ), 0, 0, 90, color, thickness, 8, 0);
```